# extract specific columns from dataset using AWK

Tags: bash, shell, awk, gawk

I am trying to apply simple awk script to the dataset file.
The file has 150 columns, I need cols between 20 to 30 only.

below is the script I used to get the records with field between 20 to 30.

## code

```
BEGIN{}
{
for(f=20;f<=30;f++){
    print $f;
    }
}
```

I dont know why I get each value of the 10 fields in next line.

That is,

## sample dataset

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 2 3 4 5 6 7 
3 3 3 4 5 6 7
4 4 4 4 5 6 7
5 5 5 5 5 6 7
6 6 6 6 6 6 7
7 7 7 7 7 7 7

I get output as 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
2
2
3
4
5
6
7
...so on
```

Comment: *Use the print statement to produce output with simple, standardized formatting. You specify only the strings or numbers to print, in a list separated by commas. They are output, separated by single spaces, followed by a newline.*

Comment: To extend melpomene's comment, look at the [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printing.html#Printing) statement

Comment: I have already tried using printf("%s",$f) but then everything is in a single row. how to have the column and records as it is? I used OFS, FS, RS too. but I cant get it to working :/

Comment: add `print` after the for loop and before the closing brace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is another way of doing the same

```
awk -v f=20 -v t=30 '{for(i=f;i<=t;i++) \
                     printf("%s%s",$i,(i==t)?"\n":OFS)}' file
```

**Notes**

1. `f` and `t` are the starting and the ending columns respectively.
2. We used the ternary operator to control the field separator between the needed columns.

---

**Edit**

If you need columns 20 thru 30 and the **last column**, below would suffice :

```
awk -v f=20 -v t=30 '{for(i=f;i<=t;i++) \
                         printf("%s%s",$i,(i==t)?OFS""$NF"\n":OFS)}' file
```

Comment: What if I need col 20 to 30 and last col(that is,150th) ? can you tell what would be the best approach?

Comment: Oh wow, true NF sands for total number of fields. so it would be the last column. Nice :) first %s print column 20 to 30 and second %s prints $NF. can you explain OFS here, how come it adds space after each column even though in printf you didnt add one like : "%s[space]%s"

Comment: By default OFS is set to space and remember we didn't touch that at all. `OFS""$NF"\n"` is essentially concatenation of string.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

```
BEGIN{FS=" ";}
{
for(f=20;f<=30;f++){
    printf("%s ",$f);
    }print "";
}
```